Excel cell center/middle alignment not truly center or middle
I have cells in Excel that, when I select center alignment, they are still slightly offset to the left of center. When I select middle vertical alignment, they are slightly offset to the bottom of middle.
Cell format (General, number, text, fraction, etc.) does not affect this.
I can not find any lead or lag space settings for each cell. How can I fix this? See image to see how each is slightly left/bottom of center.


Page layout isn't exactly Excel's strong point, nor should it be. What happens when you zoom in? How does it look when printed or exported to a PDF?

What version of Excel? Using your text and font, and testing various column widths I am unable to reproduce what your image shows.

select one of the cells of interest before taking the picture

How did you test for leading/trailing characters? =LEN()?

How does it look if you change to page layout view? Maybe it has to do with padding within a font, fixed witdth vs proportional spacing? Do you really care that it's a little off?

Thanks for the comments - it appears it's a display issue, not a setting. I should have checked that first..

Zooming in to 115% fixes the issue.  Zooming back out puts it back left of center.


1ctd)  Printing it displays as it should.
2) Version 365.
3) selecting cell doesn't move all to the right.
4) Tested leading/trailing characters by typing in each cell.
5) Page layout settings do nothing.
